# text-align: center; gives me and text-align: right; why?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I am working on a little project, the details don't really matter tho :P

But I am creating multiple div's for multiple 'categories'. Like Services, Contact etc.

But I am trying to align my `<h1 class="h1-contact">`. But it doesn't work for somereason..

I already tried looking in to other topics with this question, but somehow those answer didn't work for me.

**CSS**

```
.h1-contact {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<hr />
<br>
<div id="02">
<h1 class="h1-contact">Contact</h1>
<p>Hi</p>
```

I already tried to look in Element Inspect to look if something else was in the way of my h1-contact class, but it wasn't

Could anyone help me out? Thank you very much!

~ Justin van Dongen

**EDIT**

Element inspect 'styles' in Chrome of the h1 tag:

```
    .h1-contact {
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 1.8;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
    }

*ALL THIS IS STRIKED IN CHROME*
    .h1, h1 {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
    .h1, .h2, .h3, h1, h2, h3 {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-family: inherit;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 1.1;
        color: inherit;
    }
    h1 {
        margin: .67em 0;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 1.8;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    }
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Here are some links that may come in handy:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/justinvandongen/8Lyowreo/
Project: http://justthinq.justinvandongen.nl

Comment: What do you mean by "align?" Can you provide a better example of what you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: Your code should work. There is something overwriting your property.

Comment: @KhrisRoberts I am trying to center the text, what have I done wrong?

Comment: I pasted your html/css into jsfiddle and the H1 is centered.

Comment: @Valius79 Look at the edit of my post. I posted the element inspect of the 'styles' in Chrome, does that make a difference?

Comment: @KhrisRoberts Look at the edit of my post. I posted the element inspect of the 'styles' in Chrome, does that make a difference?

Comment: Look at this JSFiddle I made with your markup. What is wrong with the way this looks?

https://jsfiddle.net/khristopherallen/6q7u6tw3/2/

Comment: @KhrisRoberts here is the JSFiddle of my whole project. https://jsfiddle.net/justinvandongen/8Lyowreo/

Comment: But @KhrisRoberts when you maximize the width (desktop) you'll see it still aligns to the right. On mobile resolution everything is fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is simply missing or misplaced closing `</div>`. The one that is causing the h1 to right align is after the last `col-sm-6` div, but you also have one missing from `<div id="01">`, so the `<div id="02"` is nested inside of it. I would recommend running your html through a parser to verify any other missing closing elements.

I also added a clearfix to the `<div id="02" class="clearfix">` to ensure that the div has a height forcing the contact section at the bottom to start in the right spot.

This JSFiddle should cover what we have discussed. I just updated it based on your last comment.

https://jsfiddle.net/khristopherallen/vufhju4n/2/

Comment: Hey! I did now, updated my JSFiddle btw https://jsfiddle.net/justinvandongen/8Lyowreo/1/ But now my `<hr />`  is gone. How can I fix that?

Comment: I kinda know that comments like this aren't approved. But I have to say that you are my MVP of the day :)